# Get CPU load for each process

Tags: process, cpu-load

We have a system in place on AWS with a number of ubuntu servers. We have monitoring in place using AWS EC2, Consul, and Datadog.

I would like to be able to see what processes are utilizing CPU on a machine. We currently have a graph available via Datadog that shows that system.cpu.user is at 51%. I would like to see a more granular listing within system.cpu.user.

Can I make this info visible via Datadog? As a fallback, I am open to options other than Datadog.

Comment: You might find [this](http://docs.datadoghq.com/guides/monitors/) useful.

Comment: The part that I'm having trouble with is drilling into the system.cpu.user item. It is a catch-all that is composed of many pieces (tasks?). In order to see what is eating my CPU's I need to see what those pieces are and what they're doing (e.g., CPU utilization).

Comment: According to the documentation I linked it appears that you have to setup a process monitor in Datadog. I don't have the ability to test this for you hence the comment rather than an answer, but I hope the info is useful all the same.